# Por que a variável numero retorna uma string vazia quando declaro ela fora de uma função

Tags: javascript, javascript-eventos

Quando a função `printNumero` é chamada, a variável local `numero` faz o que eu queria, retorna o valor que foi inserido no input. Mas a variável `numero` global retorna uma string vazia, mesmo eu tendo colocado um valor no input dela.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>bingo.html</title>
</head>
<body>
<input type="text" id="numero">
<input type="submit" id="verificar" value="Adicione e verifique no Bingo!">

<script>
var numero = document.getElementById("numero").value;

function printNumero() {
    var numero = document.getElementById("numero").value;
    return numero;
};

var verificar = document.getElementById("verificar");
verificar.addEventListener("click", function() {
    console.log(numero);
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**EDIT**
Por que a variável `numero` local(a da função) consegue retornar o valor do input e a variável `numero` global retorna uma string vazia? Lembrando, sem o auxílio da função, é a variável global mesmo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Na hora que você faz isto:

```
var numero = document.getElementById("numero").value;
```

Você está **copiando o valor do campo** para a variável. Como ao carregar a página esse campo está vazio, a variável fica com o valor vazio. Mudanças posteriores no valor do campo não afetam a variável, porque o valor foi copiado.

A maneira mais simples de adaptar o seu código é guardar na variável o próprio campo, em vez do valor dele. Como o campo é um objeto, e não um valor primitivo (string, número, etc), a variável vai guardar uma **referência** ao campo, e não uma cópia. E você pode usar essa referência para pegar o valor atual a qualquer momento:

```
var campoNumero = document.getElementById("numero");
var verificar = document.getElementById("verificar");
verificar.addEventListener("click", function() {
    console.log(campoNumero.value); // valor no momento do clique
});
```

Comment: Muito obrigado, me ajudou bastante :)

Answer (score 1):

É que do jeito que está, você declara uma nova variável com o mesmo nome dentro do escopo da função `printNumero()` e a retorna, ou seja, o valor dela é tratado de forma separada do escopo global.

E com em nenhum momento você chama a função `printNumero()` atribuindo seu retorno a variável `numero`, a variável inicial permanece intacta.

Uma possível correção seria:

```
verificar.addEventListener("click", function() {
    numero = printNumero();
    console.log(numero);
});
```

Ou você pode apenas usar a variável em escopo global, dentro da função, sem redeclará-la. Assim:

```
function printNumero() {
    numero = document.getElementById("numero").value;
    return numero;
};
```

Daí, bastaria chamá-la antes de printar, não seria necessária a atribuição.

```
verificar.addEventListener("click", function() {
    printNumero();
    console.log(numero);
});
```

#### EDIT:

Caso não queira usar a função basta atualizar o valor dentro do callback do evento *click*:

```
verificar.addEventListener("click", function() {
    numero = document.getElementById("numero").value;
    console.log(numero);
});
```

Comment: Obrigado, mas, e se a função não existisse e eu usasse só a variável global que eu declarei, o que seria necessário fazer para que o valor não retornasse uma string vazia, ou, não tem como?

Comment: @ThomasDota, editei a resposta ;)

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda :)